# Why libgdx new version use tile unit to set the position of the camera?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to put the new version of **libgdx** 0.9.8 -> 1.0.1.

I use a tilemap and an **OrthographicCamera** with an **OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer**.

This is my camera implementation :

```
map = tileMapHelper.getMap();
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1/128f);
camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
camera.setToOrtho(false, 5, (float)(height/128f));
```

So when I try to move up the camera (just 2 pixels), I do this :

```
camera.position.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y + 2, 0);
```

Unfortunately, this operation moves up the camera 2 tiles.

How can I move my camera with only pixels ?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you have to manipulate the viewport of your camera.

Comment: Thank you ! Which viewport can I choose ? Can you explain me their role ?

Answer (score 0):

By passing a unitScale of 1/128f to the renderer, and using a camera viewport of 5 x (height/128f) you are telling libgdx you want the camera units to be tiles instead of pixels.

Either don't use tile dimensions for the camera and map renderer, or divide all of your pixel values by 128f to convert them to tile units.